# Drupal Commerce: Views and Contextual Arguments for Date Range

Tags: views, datetime, commerce

So, asked [this question over at Drupal Commerce forums](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/node/1245), and they directed me here:

I am looking for a simple way to select a part/product by the year in which it was manufactured, under a generation of products.

For instance, selecting a Schwinn bicycle model, manufactured between the years of 1971-1973. I have looked at Apache Solr and facets, but running a Solr instance looks to be a bit resource and database intensive.

I'd like to this with minimal code, if at all possible.

Thanks in advance for your answers, and for all the independent support and thought that has gone into this module.

P.S.

As an aside, if anyone needs to do bulk product editing, I suggest creating a view, and then turning off "Overlays" under the "Core Modules" section. It makes things far more responsive, and easy to organize.

**Original method suggested by forum:**

I'd add a manufacture date datefield (using Date module) to the product. You could then use exposed filters on the date to provide blog-style listings (using arguments == contextual filters) in views. bicycles/manufacturedate/1994

**and the followup clarification:**

This method works for a single year, but not for a range of years. Unfortunately, some of my products have model ranges that span 12 years. Unless I am missing something, I would need a separate date field for each year to use the method suggested.

Is there a way to do a range of years, using a value such as 1953-1964...such that a product manufactured in 1967 would show up for that range?

Comment: Can you simplify the question? "I want to create a view so that a URL like (xxx) presents nodes like (xxx)". BTW, what you're doing isn't really about Commerce, it's just about how to use datefields with arguments (I think).

Comment: Thanks rfay... for some reason, I didn't get an update of your comment. What I ended up using was a view with contextual filters. The issue I was getting at, and am still working on is creating a combination dropdown select (non-taxonomy based), combined with a search form. The desired result is that it kicks to the node with the view applied, and the arguments/vars that the view need to operate are present in the URL. My best guess is that I need to figure out how to make the dropdown and search box work with hook_form_alter.